$f(x)$ is a differentiable function satisfying the relation $f(x)=x^2+\int_0^x e^{-t} f(x-t) dt$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^9f(k)$ is equal to

$f(x)$ is a differentiable function satisfying the relation $f(x)=x^2+\int_0^x e^{-t} f(x-t) dt$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^9f(k)$ is equal to

I first differentiated the given relation on both sides w.r.t. $x$ and obtained
$f'(x)=2x+e^{-x} f(0).$
Substituting $0$ in the given relation, we have $f(0) = 0$.
By substituting the value
we get $f'(x)=2x$.
Now integrating this on both sides
would result in $f(x)=x^2+c$;
again for $x=0$ we get $c = 0$.
Thus
$f(x)=x^2$.
Turns out the answer is $$f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^3}{3}.$$
Could someone please explain where I went wrong?

We really can't know where you went wrong unless you edit to include all your work.

Tutorial of MathJax and please do not use images.

Okay,sorry i am new to Math stackexchange

Thanks for editing!

I integrated it on both sides

Let $v=x-t,$ $$\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}f(x-t)dt=e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{v}f(v)dv$$
Differentiate the equation on both sides w.r.t $x$ gives:$$f'(x)=2x+f(x)-e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{v}f(v)dv=2x+f(x)-f(x)+x^2$$
$$f'(x)=2x+x^2$$
Then solve the ODE with initial condition $f(0)=0$.

Thanks,but i do have a solution(which is the one you have answered).But could you please tell me where i went wrong ?

@Electro $f'(x)=2x$ is not true. The derivative of $\int_0^x e^{-t} f(x-t)dt$ is not $0$ . Check my steps.

but why am i not allowed to differentiate it directly,i.e without using king's rule ?

@Electro  If you calculate it by using the definition, you'll know this kind of function cannot be differentiated directly.

@Electro Leibniz integral rule may help.

Oh,okay.My defination of leibni rule was wrong .
Thanks a lot!

@Electro Feel free to accept if my answer helps.

Before differentiating use the IVth property of definite integration that
$$\int_{0}^{a} g(t) dt=\int_{0}^{a} g(a-t) dt.$$ Then
$$\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t} f(x-t) dt=e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x} e^{t} f(t) dt.$$
Next you get
$$f(x)=x^2+e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t} f(t) dt.~~~~~~(*)$$
Note that $f(0)=0$.Now differentiate w.r.t.x
$$f'(x)=2x-e^{-x}\int_0^{x} e^{t}f(t) dt+e^{-x} e^xf(x)$$
Next, use (*) to write $$f'(x)=2x-f(x)-x^2+f(x)\implies f'(x)=2x+x^2\implies f(x)=x^2+x^3/3+C$$
$f(0)=0$ gives $C=0$.

Here is an alternative solution using the Laplace transform. Taking the transform of both sides of the equation, we get
$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}=\mathcal{L}\{x^2\}+\mathcal{L}\{e^{-x}\}\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\} =\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{1}{s+1}\,\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}
$$
$$
\implies\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}=\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{2}{s^4}
\implies f(x)=x^2+\frac{x^3}{3}.
$$
